# React - Component, Element and Instance

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in React. After going through the React documentation and some tutorials I came across some concepts referenced as **Component**, **Element** and **Instance**.

In the docs **Component** is described as:

**Conceptually, components are like JavaScript functions. They accept arbitrary inputs (called “props”) and return React elements describing what should appear on the screen.**

One way to create a react component is:

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    //return react element
  }
});
```

It is also said that the **render** method should return a react **element**. Element is described as:

**React elements are simply plain old JavaScript objects used to describe how the HTML for the component should look**

One way to create react element is:

```
React.createElement(...);
```

I also came to know that when a component is rendered an **Instance** of it is created.

Initially I thought that Elements and Instances are same but later came to know that they are different(let me know if I am wrong). **I am not getting why and how they differ from each other and how these concepts are related. Please help me.**

Comment: What documents are you reading?, looks old, have you read this? https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @Kunukn I am referring to the same document you have mentioned.

Comment: @Sattyaki https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html

Comment: That blog is from 2015 december. React have evolved since. If you are new I recommend to use the new syntax `extends React.Component` and avoid or wait with `React.createClass`. Prerequisite to understand the blog is to know what JavaScript class + instances are and what html elements are. I recommend to start with newer blog/articles or with their current tutorial.